# ordering a list on jetpack compose Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using a lazy column to show a list, the items in the list have the attribute `isWeekTopic` which is a `Boolean`, in the list I need to show first those elements that have `isWeekTopic = true`, and then show the ones that have `isWeekTopic = false`, the items that has `isWeekTopic = true` are going to change every week.

I managed to print the ones that has `isWeekTopic = true` with a header on the design, but I can't make them the first elements to show. this is my code

```
LazyColumn(
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 16.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(18.dp)
            ) {
                items(
                    items = topicsskill,
                    key = { topicsSkill ->
                        topicsSkill.topicsId
                    }
                ) { topicsSkill ->
                    TopicsItemComposable(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth(),
                        topicsItem = topicsSkill,
                        onItemClicked = { onItemClicked(it) }
                    )
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just reorder `topicsskill`. You can do it either in compose or in viewmodel.

Comment: Read sticky header of lazy column, it will resolve your problem, [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `sortedBy` can do what you need.

Sample data class:

```kotlin
data class Something(
    val title: String,
    val isWeekTopic: Boolean
)
```

Extension to create dummy list:

```kotlin
fun createList(size: Int): List<Something> = List(size = size) { index ->
    Something(
        title = "something $index",
        isWeekTopic = Random.nextBoolean()
    )
}
```

Extension to order the list:

```kotlin
fun List<Something>.ordered(
    weekTopicFirst: Boolean
): List<Something> =
    if (weekTopicFirst) this.sortedBy { !it.isWeekTopic }
    else this.sortedByDescending { !it.isWeekTopic }
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val items = createList(size = 15)
    
println("printing true first")
items.ordered(weekTopicFirst = true).forEach { println(it) }
    
println("printing false first")
items.ordered(weekTopicFirst = false).forEach { println(it) }
```

You can try this code [here](https://pl.kotl.in/HlRLh_cyk).

In Compose, just pass the list normally:

```kotlin
// just an example scenario, ideally it comes from a viewmodel
val dummyItems = createList(size = 15).ordered(weekTopicFirst = true)

LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(all = 16.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(space = 16.dp)
) {
    items(
        items = dummyItems,
        key = { it.title } // should be unique
    ) { something ->
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Text(text = something.title)
            Text(text = "week topic: ${something.isWeekTopic}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As to "just an example scenario, ideally it comes from a viewmodel" - i would underline that, ordering list directly in composable is a performance killer. At least do this line inside `remember` and it would be much better